# What is the Android replacement of Wifimanager.disconnect() from API 29 onwards?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-10.0

I have a use case to disconnect from connected wifi and fall back to the mobile data. Before Api 29 I used to use Wifimanager.disconnect() but Api 29 onwards I couldn't find the way to do the same process. Is there a way to achieve the use case from Api29?